# After executing "hash -r" nothing can be installed (my concern is installing npm and nodejs)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ubuntu, npm

I want to install latest version of npm and nodejs. I need it to run angular js project.
I installed npm using "sudo apt-get install npm".
But it installed 1.3.0 something version which is not latest. 
I searched for how to remove npm (to install latest) on net and I found to do "hash -r" and further some process.

But when I executed this command, nothing could be installed.
Even I cannot see the currently installed version by using "npm -v". This command shows nothing.

:(

What do the "hash -r" command do?
How to undo it?
How do I do now to install npm and nodejs on ubuntu?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Do `sudo apt-get remove npm`, and download the installer from https://nodejs.org/en/

Packages installed by `apt-get` should only be removed with `apt-get`

Comment: Thanks for help.. but I am getting "E: Invalid operation uninstall" error.

Comment: Sorry, try `remove`

Comment: Sorry... I couldn't understand. Can you please explain what to do exactly?
I tried "sudo apt-get remove npm" 
but it gave result as 
"Package 'npm' is not installed, so not removed" 
Please help me, I am unable to install npm and nodejs.